# display user information in fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Android Studio 3.5.

I built bottom navigation with fragment and then I'm trying to display user information such as (name - email - image and so on) that is  retrieved from a Firebase store .. when reach to :

```java
documentReference.addSnapshotListener (this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, 
            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        t_name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("name"));
        t_email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));
    }
});
```

It gave me a red line under the code... When click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it gives me solve put cast (Executor) before (this) after the cast the app doesn't work ...

[image: red line]

I don't know how to solve it ..

**Note:** This is on fragment not in activity

And if I want to display image that retrieve from Firebase... How can I do it?

Thanks

### account Fragment

```java
public class accountFragment extends Fragment {
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userID;
    TextView logout_account , t_name , t_email , t_country ;

    public  accountFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    t_country = v.findViewById(R.id.t_country);
    t_email = v.findViewById(R.id.t_email);
    t_name = v.findViewById(R.id.t_name);

    DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("eng.users").document(userID);
    documentReference.addSnapshotListener (this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, 
                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            t_name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("name"));
            t_email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));
            t_country.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("country"));
        }
    });
}
```

### Activity_account.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".categories.accountFragment">


    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/banner_pro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/banner2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/mypic"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorDarkBlue"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    >

    <TextView
    android:textColor="@color/colorDarkBlue"
    android:id="@+id/t_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/t_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:text="Email"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/t_country"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="country"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/logout_account"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/banner_pro"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="LogOut"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow mohamed! For future questions, please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on

```
documentReference.addSnapshotListener (this, ...
```

use

```
documentReference.addSnapshotListener (getActivity(), ...
```

You are in a fragment